# simplification of a complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I just don't understand the following calculus from my lectures.
It says that,

$$\int_0^M \left|e^{i(M^2-t^2)-2tM)}\right|dt=\int_{0}^Me^{-2tM}dt,$$
where $M$ is a constant. Why does the first term disappear?

Comment: Has absolute value one as it is $e^{ix}, x$ real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|e^{i(M^2-t^2)-2tM}|=|e^{i(M^2-t^2)}|e^{-2tM}=e^{-2tM}$.